# NVME disk in enclosure not working

Tags: disk, nvme

DISK - INTEL SSDPEKNW512G8L
ENCLOSURE - RTL9210B-CG
trying with USB self powered hub and as a standalone (adapter+drive)

don't know why it's not showing up.

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda

/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
Standards:
        Likely used: 1
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       0       0
        heads           0       0
        sectors/track   0       0
        --
        Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:           0 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:           0 MBytes
        cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
        IORDY not likely
        Cannot perform double-word IO
        R/W multiple sector transfer: not supported
        DMA: not supported
        PIO: pio0
 sudo smartctl -a  /dev/sda
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [aarch64-linux-6.1.21-v8+] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Read NVMe Identify Controller failed: scsi error unsupported field in scsi command

 635.143560] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  635.253730] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=9210, bcdDevice=f0.01
[  635.253764] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  635.253782] usb 1-1.2: Product: RTL9210B-CG
[  635.253798] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Realtek
[  635.253811] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 802345978987
[  635.290122] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  635.290965] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[  636.322183] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Realtek  RTL9210B-CG      1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  636.323291] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  636.331656] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  636.331692] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : 0x5 [current]
[  636.331708] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x24 ASCQ=0x0
[  636.331731] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[  636.331746] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0-byte physical blocks
[  636.332355] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[  636.332374] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 37 00 00 08
[  636.332957] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  636.334444] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Comment: I have a SSK Aluminum M.2 NVME SATA SSD Enclosure Adapter, and with it, it shows all the details of my NVMe drive that is in it where yours shows this "Read NVMe Identify Controller failed:". So I assume it is your adapter.

Comment: i tried it in windows 10 without additional power supply hub and its working.